# Почему java воспринмает интерфейс comparator как функциональный

Tags: java, интерфейс, lambda, лямбда-выражение

Недавно ознакомился с лямбда-выражениями и узнал, что с их помощью можно реализовать `Comparator`. Но мне не даёт покоя то, что в этом интерфейсе объявлено два не статических и не реализованных по умолчанию метода: `compare()` и `equals()`. И несмотря на это, интерфейс считается функциональным, и метод `compare()` может быть реализован с помощью лябда-выражений.

Как так? Почему метод `equals()` не воспринимается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Интерфейс Comparator функциональный, потому что equals() - относится к public-методу класcа Object.

Интерфейсы объявляют абстрактные методы относящиеся к public методам Object, но обычно делают это неявным образом и эти методы не учитываются.